# Bootstrap CDN overwrites despite loading order in Jade, Stylus

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pug, stylus

I am using stylus and jade for my frontend. For convenience I am getting bootstrap from the cdn source and overwriting a few rules here and there. Most of the rules are okay, but I can't seem to overwrite this rule in the navbar. I changed the `background-color` just fine but I can't change the links in a dropdown.

My `layout.jade` looks like this:

```
include mixins

doctype
html
head
  title #{title} - Project Name

  link(href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')


  // js imports
  script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js')
  script(src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js')
  script(src='https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js')

  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
body
+nav("Project Name", "dropdown_menu")
  +nav_item( "/") Home
  +nav_item( "/about" ) About
  +nav_item( "/" ) Contact
  +nav_item_dropdown( "#" )( label="Dropdown")
    +nav_item( "#" ) Action
    +nav_item( "#" ) Another action
    +nav_item( "#" ) Something else here
    +nav_divider
    +nav_header Nav header
    +nav_item( "#" ) Separated link
    +nav_item( "#" ) One more separated link
header
  h1 Messaging
.container
  .jumbotron
    h1 Hello!
.container
  .row
    .main-content.col-md-8
      block content
    .sidebar.col-md-4
      block sidebar
footer
  p Running on node with Express, Jade and Stylus
```

I run my own stylesheet last to make sure I overwrite but it isn't working. I'm not sure how this would happen as it seems like everything is right to me. Do the bootstrap `js` scripts call anything to overwrite when they load?

My `mixins.jade` is as follows:

```
//- Navbar mixins
mixin nav(name, id, style)
    - var style = (typeof style === 'undefined') ? "default" : style
    nav( role="navigation", class=["navbar", "navbar-" + style] )
        .navbar-header
            button.navbar-toggle.collapsed( type="button", data-toggle="collapse", data-target="#" + id, aria-expanded="false", aria-controls="navbar")
                span.sr-only Toggle navigation
                span.icon-bar
                span.icon-bar
                span.icon-bar
            a.navbar-brand(href="#")= name

        .collapse.navbar-collapse( id=id )
            ul.nav.navbar-nav
                block

mixin nav_item(href, active)
    li(class=active): a( href=href )
        block

mixin nav_item_dropdown(href, active)
    li(class=["dropdown", active])
        a.dropdown-toggle( href=href, data-toggle="dropdown", role="button", aria-expanded="false" )= attributes.label
            span.caret
        ul.dropdown-menu( role="menu" )
            block

mixin nav_divider
    li.divider

mixin nav_header
    li.dropdown-header
        block

//- End navbar mixins
```

Comment: Can you confirm that formatting got lost in the paste? Looking at this, the template shouldn't even render.

Additionally, I'm not suggesting this is the issue, but you should sync the versions between your bootstrap css and javascript, they're pretty far apart and there's always a chance something is getting lost there (although doubtful).

Reformatted with latest bootstrap version here: https://gist.github.com/jmervine/f77b8858142d3e79b89b

Comment: Also, can you include your mixin's file, the issue may lie there.

Comment: I added the `mixins.jade` file. This felt like a likely culprit to me as well, but I just don't see what it could be there. It only gives names to classes as far as I can tell.

Comment: It definitely has something to do with `mixins.jade`, when I remove `"navbar-" + style` from the fourth line it sort of works. Still not sure how this would cause anything to happen because it should resolve as `navbar-default` which is defined as new css in my file.

Comment: Is `active` in the `nav_item` and `nav_item_dropdown` mixins getting written as "undefined" in the rendered html? Not sure if/why that would impact anything, but worth checking. Otherwise, might need to see the rendered html and css as well.